# IPv4 header checksum calculation ,what am I missing

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, tcp

Been trying to fix this code for a while with no luck,tried different implementations that calculate the IPv4 header checksum,however their output is vastly different from my programs output:

Function I stole from the linux [kernel](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/checksum_64.h#L45) to do this:

```
static inline uint16_t ip_fast_csum(const void *iph, unsigned int ihl){

     unsigned int sum;

     asm("  movl (%1), %0\n"
         "  subl $4, %2\n"
         "  jbe 2f\n"
         "  addl 4(%1), %0\n"
         "  adcl 8(%1), %0\n"
         "  adcl 12(%1), %0\n"
         "1: adcl 16(%1), %0\n"
         "  lea 4(%1), %1\n"
         "  decl %2\n"
         "  jne      1b\n"
         "  adcl $0, %0\n"
         "  movl %0, %2\n"
         "  shrl $16, %0\n"
         "  addw %w2, %w0\n"
         "  adcl $0, %0\n"
         "  notl %0\n"
         "2:"
     /* Since the input registers which are loaded with iph and ihl
        are modified, we must also specify them as outputs, or gcc
        will assume they contain their original values. */
         : "=r" (sum), "=r" (iph), "=r" (ihl)
         : "1" (iph), "2" (ihl)
         : "memory");
     return ( uint16_t)sum; }
```

Sample header(bytes):
45009d4326400406af6cd052ed12ac10a51

Section of my program that calls the above function assigns the checksum to the header and prints the header as well as the checksum:

```
  newpacket.ipheader->check = ip_fast_csum ((unsigned short *) newpacket.ipheader, IP4_HDRLEN);
  debug(5,"newpacket checksum set to %0x\r\n",newpacket.ipheader->check);
  uint8_t *ipbuf=(uint8_t *)newpacket.ipheader;
  for(i=0;i<IP4_HDRLEN;i++){
   debug(5,"%0x",ipbuf[i]); 
  }debug(5,"\n");
```

debug() is just a printf() wrapper, following is sample output:

```
newpacket checksum set to 6caf
45009d4326400406af6cd052ed12ac10a51
```

Screencap from what wireshark is telling me:

[wiresharkcap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhn9B.png)

Can you help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is the function I normally use:

```
inline unsigned short csum (unsigned short *buf, int nwords) {
     unsigned long sum;

     for (sum = 0; nwords > 0; nwords--)
          sum += *buf++;
     sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
     sum += (sum >> 16);
     return (unsigned short) (~sum);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [RFC 1071](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1071), [RFC 1141](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1141), and [RFC 1624](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1624) are the sources to give you the algorithm on how to calculate the IPv4 Header Checksum.

Comment: Looks like you are calculating IP header checksum. Wireshark seems to display the TCP header checksum.

Comment: Just to expand on @SergeyA it seems you have put the IP layer checksum in the TCP layer. Or in more "official" terms. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model You are mixing up layer 3 and 4.

Comment: Hi,TCP checksum is good  in wireshark,if you look at the picture only ip chekcsum is in red. i've read the wikipedia section on this a few times,still seem to be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand a bit more @SergeyA from the comments and myself a bit more. If you look at the file you referenced [above](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/checksum_64.h#L45), you will notice in the comment for that function

> ip_fast_csum - Compute the IPv4 header checksum efficiently.

You do not want to compute the IPv4 header checksum you want the TCP checksum. These are separate layers in the OSI model found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). To calculate the TCP checksum you need to do as [these](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPChecksumCalculationandtheTCPPseudoHeader-2.htm) fine people describe.

Using just the kernel code as you wanted to do earlier there is a function found here which should calculate the TCP checksum. Below I'll copy it's description and header.

```
static inline __sum16 tcp_v4_check(int len, __be32 saddr,
                                    __be32 daddr, __wsum base)
```

> - Calculate(/check) TCP checksum

If however you'd like to do it the hard way. Looking in that same file you referenced you can calculate the pseudo header for TCP packets using the function.

```
csum_tcpudp_nofold(__be32 saddr, __be32 daddr, __u32 len,
                 __u8 proto, __wsum sum)
```

> Returns the pseudo header checksum the input data. Result is  32bit
>   unfolded.

This is just the psuedo header though from there you need to compute the total checksum which I BELIEVE (not 100% sure) you can just use the function you showed earlier to compute if you pad the pseudo header described earlier onto it.

On an aside I have not checked this code but it seems pretty accurate from a first glance so [here](http://locklessinc.com/articles/tcp_checksum/) is a C/assembly way to calculate the TCP checksum.

Comment: Hi, TCP checksum is fine, I have a separate function that calculates it.wireshark shows good tcp checksum so i'm not worried about that, TCP checksum needs the tcp heder+data+ip pseudo header. this is for the ipv4 header checksum which is separate and is strictly for the ipv4 header. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_header_checksum

Comment: Ah ok my mistake from the picture you provided and the text I thought you had put the IP checksum in the TCP field. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to post this and resolve this question, I have solved this problem after trying many implemenations,the only one that works is Suricata IDPS's code.

```
    static inline uint16_t IPV4CalculateChecksum(uint16_t *pkt, uint16_t hlen)
{
    uint32_t csum = pkt[0];

    csum += pkt[1] + pkt[2] + pkt[3] + pkt[4] + pkt[6] + pkt[7] + pkt[8] +
        pkt[9];

    hlen -= 20;
    pkt += 10;

    if (hlen == 0) {
        ;
    } else if (hlen == 4) {
        csum += pkt[0] + pkt[1];
    } else if (hlen == 8) {
        csum += pkt[0] + pkt[1] + pkt[2] + pkt[3];
    } else if (hlen == 12) {
        csum += pkt[0] + pkt[1] + pkt[2] + pkt[3] + pkt[4] + pkt[5];
    } else if (hlen == 16) {
        csum += pkt[0] + pkt[1] + pkt[2] + pkt[3] + pkt[4] + pkt[5] + pkt[6] +
            pkt[7];
    } else if (hlen == 20) {
        csum += pkt[0] + pkt[1] + pkt[2] + pkt[3] + pkt[4] + pkt[5] + pkt[6] +
            pkt[7] + pkt[8] + pkt[9];
    } else if (hlen == 24) {
        csum += pkt[0] + pkt[1] + pkt[2] + pkt[3] + pkt[4] + pkt[5] + pkt[6] +
            pkt[7] + pkt[8] + pkt[9] + pkt[10] + pkt[11];
    } else if (hlen == 28) {
        csum += pkt[0] + pkt[1] + pkt[2] + pkt[3] + pkt[4] + pkt[5] + pkt[6] +
            pkt[7] + pkt[8] + pkt[9] + pkt[10] + pkt[11] + pkt[12] + pkt[13];
    } else if (hlen == 32) {
        csum += pkt[0] + pkt[1] + pkt[2] + pkt[3] + pkt[4] + pkt[5] + pkt[6] +
            pkt[7] + pkt[8] + pkt[9] + pkt[10] + pkt[11] + pkt[12] + pkt[13] +
            pkt[14] + pkt[15];
    } else if (hlen == 36) {
        csum += pkt[0] + pkt[1] + pkt[2] + pkt[3] + pkt[4] + pkt[5] + pkt[6] +
            pkt[7] + pkt[8] + pkt[9] + pkt[10] + pkt[11] + pkt[12] + pkt[13] +
            pkt[14] + pkt[15] + pkt[16] + pkt[17];
    } else if (hlen == 40) {
        csum += pkt[0] + pkt[1] + pkt[2] + pkt[3] + pkt[4] + pkt[5] + pkt[6] +
            pkt[7] + pkt[8] + pkt[9] + pkt[10] + pkt[11] + pkt[12] + pkt[13] +
            pkt[14] + pkt[15] + pkt[16] + pkt[17] + pkt[18] + pkt[19];
    }

    csum = (csum >> 16) + (csum & 0x0000FFFF);
    csum += (csum >> 16);

    return (uint16_t) ~csum;
}
```

https://github.com/inliniac/suricata/blob/master/src/decode-ipv4.h

I hope this helps others too, suricata has excellent code base,well written working code too.

Cheers and thank you for anyone that tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

I met same issue recently and I found I was wrong. Set checksum field to zero before calculate like as below:

```
newpacket.ipheader->check = 0;
newpacket.ipheader->check = ip_fast_csum ((unsigned short *) newpacket.ipheader, IP4_HDRLEN);
```